# How to get Tweet ID from post

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, tweets

I have a simple text-area where someone can type a message to be tweeted on a account.
I want to make a list of people re-tweet this tweet.

For as far as i know, i need the unique id of my tweet.
But I don't know how to fetch this.

My post:

```
$twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth('*****', '******', $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);
$twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $toTweet));
```

Can i somehow fetch the id directly from my post?

I have been searching the internet, but only seem to find ways of getting a tweet by id and not the other way around.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Doesn't `$twitteroauth->post` return an object with tweet details?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller I have printed $twitteroauth but there was nothing like an id in the array.

Comment: Do `$result = $twitteroauth->post` and print `$result`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Thank you so much <3... no homo xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of your tweet can be found in an object returned from API call:

```
$tweet = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $toTweet));
```

Now `$tweet` holds the details about your status update, including it's ID.